# Silverlight WCF service returns remote server not found error on deploy

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have been trying to host a WCF service for a Silverlight OOB application. When I run the application from my local machine it works fine. But when the same is deployed to a server, I get the following

> *Remote Server not found error.*

I used fiddler to track the error and it says

> *HTTP/1.1 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException*

Could this be some issue with the IIS settings on the server?

Comment: Enable detailed errors and visit the service URL from the server (`http://localhost/`) to see the detailed error, so you can solve this.

Comment: do you have the clientaccesspolicy on the server?

Comment: 500 errors are server errors, so look in the "Application" event log on the server, or wherever else your server like to log exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two things,

1.Check for these two files in your service root folder clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.

2.Check for the namespace of your service.you might be wrong on the namespace.

if these does not work post your web.config .

Comment: Hi .. I checked the Applciation log and this iwhat it says "Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/XXX.SVC' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.. ---> "

Comment: If I set the HttpGetEnabled to false it web.config it works fine. But my question is why is this working in local and not when deployed on server?

Comment: Then problem with your webconfig. Post your webconfig here.